# how to import several columns from diferent tables/databases into one

Tags: mysql, insert, constraint

To be a bit clear I have 3 different tables with several columns each I want to kind of create a final table   to help me explain myself better

Table A:

| id | a2 | a3 | a4 | a5 | a6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |

Table B:

| id | b2 | b3 | b4 | b5 | b6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 |

Table C:

| id | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 | c6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 31 | 32 | 33 | 34 | 35 |

What I want to achieve is creating a new table with values from the other 3 tables they all have the same id:

FinalTABLE:

| id | a2 | a3 | b2 | b5 | c3 | c4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 12 | 22 | 24 | 32 | 33 |

Comment: Does `id` is primary key in each table? Does any `id` value which is present in one table is also present in another tables with guarantee?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you really mean to "join on id":

```
SELECT a.id, a.a2, a.a3,
             b.b2, b.b5,
             ...
    FROM a
    JOIN b  USING(id)
    JOIN c  USING(id)
```

You mention building a new table from those three tables -- will you keep all the tables?  This is a RDBMS no-no, namely "redundant data".

To keep them all:

```
CREATE TABLE ABC
    SELECT ... -- that select above;
```

To use a "VIEW" (no redundancy, but fetch when needed):

```
CREATE VIEW ABC ...
    AS
    SELECT ... -- that select above;
```

To put into a different "DATABASE", use the "db.tbl" syntax:

```
CREATE ... db2.abc
    SELECT ... FROM db1.a  JOIN db1.b ...;
```